# How to send Russian and Arabic character on windowsmessages?

Tags: c#

I have 2 applications in c# that are talking via windows messages
App1: sends a message to App2

```
string msg=UserName+","+UserAge;

byte[] sarr =System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg);//

int len = sarr.Length;

COPYDATASTRUCT cds;

cds.dwData = (IntPtr)100;

cds.lpData = msg;

cds.cbData = len + 1;

result = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, wParam, ref cds);
```

App2:receives the message from App1

```
COPYDATASTRUCT sentPara = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
Type mytype = sentPara.GetType();
sentPara = (COPYDATASTRUCT)message.GetLParam(mytype);
string[] parameters = sentPara.lpData.Split(',');
```

**Problem:**
The username is in Russian and when i receive it in App2 i got question marks"???????", i think it's something in the encoding of byte array but i don't how to solve it

Comment: You're not *doing* anything with the byte array...

Comment: No i send it as it's. I also tried to change Default to UTF8 but i didn't work

Comment: Look at what you're setting `lpData` to - you're setting it to `msg`, not `sarr`. You're only using the byte array to find the length to set.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's about the byte array i just guess :)

Comment: may be if you change `cds.lpData = msg` to `cds.lpData = sarr` , it might work. Change encoding to UTF8 as well btw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# using SendMessage, problem with WM\_COPYDATA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779731/c-sharp-using-sendmessage-problem-with-wm-copydata) - please note that while the title does not match exactly, the linked post is about problems with sending a string-message with COPYDATA structure, so it matches quite well.

Comment: Please ignore the 'duplicate flag'. I did not think long enough about the issue, and now I don't know how to cancel it. In the linked post, they use something like `cbdata = str.length+1`. This is obviously wrong for multi-byte encodings, as it would surely cause the data of the message to be truncated. Please stay with your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your two applications running as two separate processes?

If so, then you cannot sent `string` directly, because it will contain some internal pointers that will not be valid in the other process's adress space. You don't know what the STRING class contains - it is hidden. Therefore, it MAY contain them, not 'surely contains'.

(Although in C#/.Net it surely contains).

You have started well: you need to pack the *contents* of that string into an raw byte array, guarantee by yourself that it contains only data and no pointers, and then send the raw array to the second process.

The core of your problem is a wrong P/Invoke definition of `COPYDATA` structure. The `lpVoid` should not be of `string` type, but should be of type `byte[]` or `IntPtr`. Once you change its type to `byte[]`, the compiler will immediatelly show you that '=msg' and '.Split' are invalid.

Please note that your current SENDING code contains only a single error: the "data length" you provided is the **length of the array** (it is correct) but also it passes the 'msg', not the array 'sarr'. After fixing the lpVoid type, just set the field to `sarr`.

Then, on the RECEIVING side, you will need to get the COPYDATA, get a `lpVoid` from it, use it as a `byte[]` and pass it to `Encoding.GetString()` method - similarly to what  **zaitsman** presented.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add a line to the second code:

```
    COPYDATASTRUCT sentPara = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
Type mytype = sentPara.GetType();
sentPara = (COPYDATASTRUCT)message.GetLParam(mytype);
var parametersDecoded = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(sentPara.lpData);
string[] parameters = parametersDecoded.Split(',');
```

Comment: Sara Saeed I only used Default because this is what you use in your app #1. The encoding has to MATCH between the two. If you need UTF8, replace `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString()` with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`.